# how to sum all columns with same id

Tags: sql

Hi i have the following results:

[image]

i need to sum up all the items that have cashamount and same Payment code = 9

i have tried this query:

```
  SELECT 
  CASE
        WHEN StoreID = 1 THEN 'CWM'
        WHEN StoreID = 2 THEN 'CWD' END as accountcode,
  DocEntry,
  PaymentCode,
  case when PaymentCode <> 1 then paymentamount end as OtherPaymentAmount,
  sum(case when PaymentCode = 1 then paymentamount end) as CashAmount,


  tenders.sapcreditcard AS sapcreditcard,
 
 --paymentamount,

 -- sum (case when PaymentCode >= 1 then paymentamount else NULL end) as Total,
  FileName, BPA_ProcessStatus, ERP_PaymentProcessed

  FROM [Plu].[dbo].[payments_header] LEFT JOIN tenders ON payments_header.PaymentCode = tenders.postenderid
    WHERE BPA_ProcessStatus='N' and ERP_PaymentProcessed='N'
  group by PaymentCode, paymentamount, docentry, storeid,sapcreditcard, FileName, BPA_ProcessStatus,ERP_PaymentProcessed, cashamount
```

what im missing?

Comment: None of the items in the example data have a `CashAmount` where `PaymentCode = 9`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause lists all the columns you want to use to create separate groups.  Yours is as follows...

```
GROUP BY
  PaymentCode,
  paymentamount,
  docentry,
  storeid,
  sapcreditcard,
  FileName,
  BPA_ProcessStatus,
  ERP_PaymentProcessed,
  cashamount
```

Any time any of these are different, you'll get a separate row.

This means that your `sum(case when PaymentCode = 1 then paymentamount end)` ends up making very little sense.

- Your `GROUP BY` says you want each different payment amount on a different row
- Your `SELECT` says you want to aggregate multiple paymounts amounts

My best guess is that you want this...

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN StoreID = 1 THEN 'CWM'
    WHEN StoreID = 2 THEN 'CWD'
  END
    AS accountcode,
  DocEntry,
  PaymentCode,
  SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentCode <> 1 THEN paymentamount END)  AS OtherPaymentAmount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentCode  = 1 THEN paymentamount END)  AS CashAmount,
  tenders.sapcreditcard,
  FileName,
  BPA_ProcessStatus,
  ERP_PaymentProcessed
FROM
  [Plu].[dbo].[payments_header]
LEFT JOIN
  tenders
    ON payments_header.PaymentCode = tenders.postenderid
WHERE
      BPA_ProcessStatus='N'
  AND ERP_PaymentProcessed='N'
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN StoreID = 1 THEN 'CWM'
    WHEN StoreID = 2 THEN 'CWD'
  END,
  DocEntry,
  PaymentCode,
  tenders.sapcreditcard,
  FileName,
  BPA_ProcessStatus,
  ERP_PaymentProcessed
```

- Added `SUM()` around the `OtherPaymentAmount` calculations, to match `CashAmount`
- Changed the `GROUP BY` to match the non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT`

***NOTE:*** In all the places where you specify a column name, your should *always* qualify it with the source table's name.